# How to convert org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]] to Array[Double] which is required by Spark MLlib

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to implement `KMeans using Apache Spark`.

```
val data = sc.textFile(irisDatasetString)
val parsedData = data.map(_.split(',').map(_.toDouble)).cache()

val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData,3,numIterations = 20)
```

on which I get the following error :

```
error: overloaded method value train with alternatives:
  (data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector],k: Int,maxIterations: Int,runs: Int)org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel <and>
  (data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector],k: Int,maxIterations: Int)org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel <and>
  (data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector],k: Int,maxIterations: Int,runs: Int,initializationMode: String)org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]], Int, numIterations: Int)
       val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData,3,numIterations = 20)
```

so I tried converting Array[Double] to Vector as shown [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/mllib-guide.html)

```
scala> val vectorData: Vector = Vectors.dense(parsedData)
```

on which I got the following error :

```
error: type Vector takes type parameters
   val vectorData: Vector = Vectors.dense(parsedData)
                   ^
error: overloaded method value dense with alternatives:
  (values: Array[Double])org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector <and>
  (firstValue: Double,otherValues: Double*)org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]])
       val vectorData: Vector = Vectors.dense(parsedData)
```

So I am inferring that **`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]]`** is not the same as Array[Double]

How can I proceed with my data as **`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]]`** ? or how can I convert **`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]] to Array[Double]`** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`KMeans.train` is expecting `RDD[Vector]` instead of `RDD[Array[Double]]`.  It seems to me that all you need to do is change

```
val parsedData = data.map(_.split(',').map(_.toDouble)).cache()
```

to

```
val parsedData = data.map(x => Vectors.dense(x.split(',').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
```

Comment: No, that is not working. I got the following error now: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.split(',').map(((x$2) => x$2.toDouble)))
       val parsedData = data.map(Vectors.dense(_.split(',').map(_.toDouble))).cache()

Comment: I tried that too. So I get parsedData of type: `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] `which I then try to convert to a Vector using: `val dataArray = parsedData.collect
val dataVector = Vectors.dense(dataArray)` which does not work out either because my dataArray is `Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]` and `Vector.dense` expects an `Array[Double]`

Comment: Why do you want the `RDD[Vector]` to be a single vector?  `KMeans.train` is expecting an `RDD[Vector]`.

Comment: You are right :) For some reason I thought I had to collect the data and then pass it to k means. Your solution works :) Thanks.

Comment: Hey Climbage, how do you write the same thing in pyspark? I am trying to get multi variate statistics on my data present in CSV file. The function is expecting RDD[Vectors]. I don't know how to get them