# Spark Mllib kmeans example, with a dataframe instead of textFile

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to run Spark (1.3.1) Mllib k-means clustering on a dataframe of floating point numbers.
I'm following the clustering example provided by Spark

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/mllib-clustering.html

However, instead of a text file, I'm using a dataframe composed of one column of doubles (for simplicity). I need to convert this to a vector for the Kmeans function, as per Mllib docs. So far I have this

```
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
    val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s(0))).cache()
```

and I receive the error

```
error: overloaded method value dense with alternatives:
(values: Array[Double])org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector and
(firstValue: Double,otherValues: Double*)org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
cannot be applied to (Any)
val parsedData = sample2.map(s => Vectors.dense(s(1))).cache()
                                          ^
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

I have read this similar post, but I didn't find it similar enough:
[How to turn a known structured RDD to Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555604/how-to-turn-a-known-structured-rdd-to-vector/27556734#27556734)
and this one [How to convert org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]] to Array[Double] which is required by Spark MLlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834210/how-to-convert-org-apache-spark-rdd-rddarraydouble-to-arraydouble-which-is)
which deals with text data

Comment: So this question exists in the context of Spark running on a Hadoop cluster, where a table was queried using Hive. Hence the dataframe. I suspect this will become an increasingly common scenario as more organisations move to Hadoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
val parsedData = data.rdd.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.getDouble(0))).cache()
```

if data is a dataframe of a single column of doubles this should work. 
if you have more columns in your dataframe then just add more gets, like:

```
val parsedData = data.rdd.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.getDouble(0),s.getDouble(1))).cache()
```

Comment: Thank you Doctor, that was what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since `import org.apache.spark.sql.Row` can store values of any type its `apply` method has a following signature:

```
 def apply(i: Int): Any
```

and `Vectors.dense` expects `Double` as an argument. There are a couple of ways to handle this. Lets assume you're want to extract values from column `x`. First of all you can pattern match over a Row constructor:

```
data.select($"x").map {
    case  Row(x: Double) => Vectors.dense(x)
}
```

If you prefer positional approach you use pattern matching over the value returned from apply:

```
data.select($"x").map(row => row(0) match {
    case x: Double => Vectors.dense(x)
})
```

Finally you can use `toDouble` method:

```
data.select($"x").map(r => Vectors.dense(r.getDouble(0)))
```

`select` part is optional, but it makes easier to pattern match over a Row and protects you from some naive mistakes like passing a wrong index to `get`.

If ever want to extract larger number of columns going one-by-one can be cumbersome. In this case something like this could be useful:

```
data.select($"x", $"y", $"z").map(r => Vectors.dense(
    r.toSeq.map({ case col: Double => col }).toArray)
)
```

Comment: In the first case, would you not write: _parsedData = data.map { case  Row(x :Double, _) => Vectors.dense(x) }_ ? I get a "type mismatch" error elsewise.

Comment: Are you sure it is not `scala.MatchError`? If so I've updated an answer to avoid the problems with matching over a whole row.